# right click for menu with choices (to change font size)?

Tags: fonts, mouse, popup, menus

I am using emacs 26.1 under macos.  when I right-click with the mouse, emacs seems to want to select the region.  alas, I would prefer to see a popup menu where I can select a few choices that I would like to choose---save file, close buffer, increase font size, decrease font size, change fore/background theme.  is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Library [`mouse3.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/mouse3.el) gives you what you request: a context-dependent right-click popup menu that's configurable.

See [Mouse3](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Mouse3) for a complete description, screenshots, and details.  By default such menus are region-related if the region is active, and it is global and click-position-related if not.